# Multiple homes for multiple languages

Tags: multisite, customization, home-url

I want to have multiples homes, for use multiples languages.

For do for example:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'en.bz6.org')
    defime('WPLANG', 'en');
else
    efime('WPLANG', 'es');
```